# Execute after setTimeout finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Probably not very suitable title, but the question is the following.

I've got this piece of code

`var someprogram = function(){
    if(stopprocess) return;
    //do things 
    setTimeout(someprogram, 1000);
}
setTimeout(someprogram, 1000);`

Sofar it works. After some number ot iterations, lets say 12, stopprocess is true and whole thing stops. I want to do some more things after the return. So the question is what is the best way to rewrite the structute to be able to do so? Because I need the timeout, but I don't know how else to stop the whole thing without using a return-statement. Any ideas? (I have only one javascript file for this task)

Comment: callback function as argument or just execute simple function?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/os26vgc5/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/os26vgc5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this one works for you:

```
var someprogram = function() { 
    if(stopprocess) {
        //do the rest

    } else {
        //do things 
        setTimeout(someprogram, 1000); 
    }
} 

setTimeout(someprogram, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

there are many ways to do this simple way is to write all your logic in a function and execute it.

```
    var logic = function(){
       //do things 
     }
```

and execute it before return

```
var someprogram = function(){
    if(stopprocess){ 
       logic(); // your code is executed now
       return;
   }

    setTimeout(someprogram, 1000);
}
setTimeout(someprogram, 1000);
```

Comment: @user4065758 i am doing on your behalf +1, but i think it is copy of Trinimon answer